# WordPress Multisite logout conflict

Tags: multisite, authentication, logout, bug

I have a WordPress Multisite setup with several sub sites.

I am having an issue when logging out of one of the sub sites that leaves the user logged into the main site which was the entry point or site by which I logged in. I have an example recorded in this video: http://www.screencast.com/t/fM9prj7KOS

I am using a Twenty Twelve theme with minimal plugins -- none of which in the video are affecting any kind of authentication/login (i.e. a membership plugin).

This is causing problems when I do activate my membership plugin. I have all members log into a common portal (mysitedotcom/member as in the video) from which they can then easily access all of their network sites nicely.

Logging out of any of the sub sites (ones not used to log in initially) does in fact log the user out of the sub site, however navigating back to the original member login portal shows the user completely logged into that particular network subsite/blog.

This seems to be a bug.

Can anyone else confirm this and help find a solution?